# Kendo UI Javascript Widgets [Custom] - Unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, kendo-ui

I am trying to build some custom widgets using Kendo UI, and these widgets are expected to use Kendo Data sources which will read data from server [REST kind of URLs].

Are there any resources/Samples on how to write unit tests for these custom Kendo Widgets, which I can refer?

Comment: What is preventing you from unit testing them as they are?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you!, may be I need to rephrase my question - I am looking for some resources which I can refer to write Unit tests for the widgets I am creating [using Widget.extend({...});].

Comment: Still not clear. What is preventing you from testing them now? Why don't you post some code and say what the difficulties are?